# How to use global variable in Inline Assembly in Greenhills Compiler?

Tags: c, embedded, inline-assembly, greenhills

I want to use a global variable in inline assembly.

> asm("    LDR R0,g_TsInitStackPointerAddress");

Here g_TsInitStackPointerAddress is a global variable. While compiling its not showing any error .

But while linking it shows the following error

> [elxr] (error) out of range: 0x1001326 (unsigned) didn't fit in 12
>   bits      while performing relocation type R_ARM_POOL (4) at address
>   0x10013e0      from InitStack+0x20 (drv.o(.text)+0x1a4),       to
>   g_TsInitStackPointerAddress+0x0 ((COMMON)+0xb6)

Here My function name is InitStack and File name is drv. I am unable to understand the error.

Processor Used : Cortex R4
Compiler : Greenhills

Comment: It seems your variable is too small? Maybe you should check the size of R0 register and the size of your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution

> __asm("g_TsInitStackPointerAddress_a: DCD g_TsInitStackPointerAddress ");

Give this statement inside that function then it'll take that variable in the inline assembly

Comment: I believe a safer way to do this is to use the `ldr=` pseudo-instruction, as seen here: http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/251-how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture/ This will let the assembler decide where to place the constant pool (e.g., after the end of the function), rather than forcing you to place it manually yourself.