# C function access to R0 to R12 registers

Tags: greenhills

I need to write the C function that will return the value of a specific hardware register.  For example R0.

I am unclear from the GHS documentation how this is done with the macros provided by the GHS Compiler.

```
uint32_t readRegRx(void)
{
   uint32_t x = 0U;
   __asm("MOV Rx, ??");
   return x;
}
```

What is the syntax in the GHS compiler for referencing a local variable as an argument to an inline assembly instruction?

I've seen this in the GHS documentation:

```
asm int mulword(a,b)
{
%con a %con b
   mov r0,a
   mov r1,b
   mul r0,r1,r0
%con a %reg b
   mov r0,a
   mul r0,b,r0
%reg a %con b
   mov r0,b
   mul r0,a,r0
%reg a %reg b
   mul r0,a,b
%con a %mem b
   mov r0,a
   ldr r1,b
   mul r0,r1,r0
%mem a %con b
   ldr r0,a
   mov r1,b
   mul r0,r1,r0
%mem a %mem b
   ldr r0,a
   ldr r1,b
   mul r0,r1,r0
%error
}
```

But this isn't exactly what I want, I think.   The example from the documention above describes a function taking arguments.   The return value is implicitly in R0.

In my case, what I want is to use a plain C function, with embedded inline assembly to read a register (R-anything) and store the value in a local variable in the function.

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255773/2189500)?  Also, trying to read registers this way seems a bit dubious.  Among other problems, calling a function can change what gets stored where.  Might a debugger be a better choice?

Comment: Yep. Aware.The purpose is making a low level hardware monitor CLI over a UART.  In use, there won't be a debugger on the target.   It's specific.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, since you say R0 is used as the return value, it would seem like you could just have an empty asm block to return it. `asm int readRegR0(){}`  However, given that the caller is going to know that whatever's in R0 is going to get overwritten by the call, the value in R0 is likely to be pretty meaningless.

Comment: R0 was an example.  All of the R# are interesting to me.  In a GNU (arm-none-eabi) environment, I can simply write:    `register unsigned int r4 asm("r4"); ` and then the symbol `r4` is a local variable to read.    Suppress why.   The question was, in GHS compiler environment, what the idiom was there to do the same functionality as `register unsigned int rX asm("rX");` for some arbitrary X.  Thanks.

Comment: That's not quite true of gnu: *The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm*, so using this to read registers is a bit iffy.  Also, if you know how to return r0, can't you use something like `mov r0, r5` for reading r5?  I don't have GHS, so I'm unable to experiment.

Comment: Thanks.  That's actually an obvious answer that I just overlooked.  `mov r0, r5` (for the GHS environment).  I was trying to read more than one register at a time but `mov r0, r5` example is sufficient.   I have the full GHS platform and so I can experiment with GNU tools or GHS tools.   Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I received information from the GHS support and it addresses the means to read hardware registers (Rn) within C functions analogous to the extended GNU ARM features.  The following applies to GHS compiler usage, not GNU compiler usage:

"For asm macro purposes (use within an asm macro), it's probably best to use the enhanced GNU asm syntax, and you'll want to turn on "Accept GNU **asm** statements" (--gnu_asm)."

```
int bar(void)
{
   int a;
   __asm__("mov r0, %0" : : "r"(a)); // move a to r0. Replace r0 to suit.
   // Stuff
  return a;
}
```

Alternative method:

```
asm void readR0(r0Val)

{

%reg r0Val

    mov r0Val,r0

}


void foo(void)

{

    register int regValReg = 0;
    readR0(regValReg);

    // Stuff
}
```